# Sass media query not working

Tags: sass

I am having trouble with my media queries in Sass - I am a beginner. If you have time can you take a look at my project and let me know if you can see why my media query is not working? I have one in the _body partial.

https://w.trhou.se/grhzs023qb

```
columns {
  @media #{$break-narrow} { 
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */ 
    column-count: 2; 
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Problem is solved, Thank you